# Show $\epsilon[\frac{x}{\epsilon}] \rightarrow x$ when $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

The question is to show that $\epsilon[\frac{x}{\epsilon}] \rightarrow x$ for $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

Here, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$.

Intuitively, it does not make sense to me, since I would have to evaluate the integral part/floor function, before considering the limit?

Any small hint would be appreciated!

Comment: The question doesn't make sense after your edit: what is the floor of an element of $\Bbb{R}^n$ for $n > 1$?

Comment: @RobArthan you're right, it's all seeming like mush to me now. Maybe context might help you understand what I am missing/getting wrong. $\epsilon$ here is a scaling factor. Say, I am in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then, $x=\epsilon(y+k)$, where $y$ comes from the unit square, $k \in \mathbb{Z}^2$. The idea is to use the unit cell as a reference, and think of some domain $\Omega$ as being covered by these much smaller $\epsilon$-cells.

Comment: My first comment wasn't right and I've deleted it. The likely answer to my second comment is that $\lfloor (x_1, \ldots, x_n)\rfloor = (\lfloor x \rfloor, \ldots, \lfloor x_n \rfloor)$. If that's right, then I think the result isn't hard to prove by thinking of a mesh where the cells have edge size $\varepsilon$ so that $\lfloor x \varepsilon\rfloor$ identifies which cell $x$ is in.

Comment: If you find limits of sequences easier to deal with than continuous functions, you may also find it convenient to first consider the case $\epsilon=x/n$ for an integer $n$, then consider how other values of $\epsilon$ relate to that case

Comment: Intuitively, it *does* make sense to me. For simplicity, let's suppose $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and let $x=[x].d_1d_2d_3\ldots$ be its decimal expansion. If $\epsilon=10^{-n}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$, then 
$$\epsilon\left[\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right]=10^{-n}[10^n[x]+d_1\ldots d_n.d_{n+1}\ldots]=10^{-n}(10^n[x]+d_1\ldots d_n)=[x].d_1\ldots d_n.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First take the case $n=1$ . . .

Fix x$\in\mathbb{R}$.

Then for any nonzero $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
\frac{x}{\epsilon}-1 < \left\lfloor\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right\rfloor
\le\frac{x}{\epsilon}
$$
so for $\epsilon > 0$ we get
\begin{align*}
&
\epsilon\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}-1\right) < \epsilon
\left\lfloor\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right\rfloor
\le\epsilon\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
x-\epsilon < \epsilon\left\lfloor\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right\rfloor\le x
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \epsilon\left\lfloor\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right\rfloor=x
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
and for $\epsilon < 0$ we get
\begin{align*}
&
\epsilon\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}-1\right) > \epsilon
\left\lfloor\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right\rfloor
\ge\epsilon\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
x-\epsilon > \epsilon\left\lfloor\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right\rfloor\ge x
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^-} \epsilon\left\lfloor\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right\rfloor=x
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \epsilon\left\lfloor\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right\rfloor=x
\qquad\;\;\,
$$
which completes the proof for the case $n=1$.

For $n > 1$, simply apply the above result for each coordinate of $x$.